# How to reset a local airflow webserver user's password

Tags: airflow, airflow-webserver

I forgot my local airflow webserver password, it is possible to reset it?

I tried to create a new user, but it say that my account already exists, so I would like to reset the password.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just deleted my user and created another with the same name, everything is working fine.

**Steps:**

1. `airflow users delete -u user_name -e email` (or simply providing user should also do the work).
2. Again add the same user as below (for airflow versions >2):

```
airflow users create --username admin --firstname admin --lastname admin --role Admin --email admin
```

Comment: Just wanted to say, there is a lot more you can do with `airflow cheat-sheet`. It took me way too long to realize how you can manage airflow with it.

Comment: @devinho thanks but I wish steps were added too.

Steps:
1> airflow users delete -u user_name -e email 
(or simply providing user should also do the work).

2> Again add the same user as below(for airflow versions >2):
airflow users create --username admin --firstname admin --lastname admin --role Admin --email admin

Comment: @Brijesh thanks for contribution, I added it above

Answer (score 7):

Airflow's own CLI doesn't have option to reset users password, but you can use Flask(framework that airflow is using) cli to do this

type
`FLASK_APP=airflow.www.app flask fab reset-password`

Answer (score 2):

While there's no way to reset password for an existing user. You may delete the user and create a new one.

To list active users:

```
airflow users list
```

To delete an user:

```
airflow users delete -u <username>
```

**Note:** using both identifiers like username and email will throw an error. You should stick to either one of them.

To create an user:

```
airflow users create --username <username> --password <password> --role Admin --firstname <firstname> --lastname <lastname> --email <email>
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Delete the existing user (or simply providing user should also do the work).

> airflow users delete -u user_name -e email.

2. Again add the same user as below(for airflow versions >2):

> airflow users create --username admin --firstname admin --lastname
> admin --role Admin --email admin

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to change the password of another user (as an admin)

- `FLASK_APP=airflow.www.app flask fab reset-password`

  - executed on the airflow-webserver or airflow-scheduler
  - will ask for username password interactively
- via the Airflow REST API

  - [Update a user](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/patch_user)
- via the Airflow UI , Security > List users > Show record (the loupe icon) > Show User

  - You have a "reset password" button there.